# Passing request from subUri to local server by NGinx

Tags: nginx, configuration, proxy

I can't find a mistake in my NGinx config. I have a website launched on `http://local_ip:8079` and need to make it accesible by outer usage by the url `http://example.com/judge`. So, page served localy at url `http://local_ip:8079/home.html` to be accessible by `http://example.com/judge/home.html` and so on. I made a config:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /judge/
    {
        proxy_pass http://local_ip:8079/;
        proxy_redirect / http://example.com/judge/;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    }
}
```

Pages are loaded but scripts and images appear in webpage source with unchanged url (i.e. `/style.css`) and are not loaded by browser. Which directive I should add?

Answer (score 0):

proxy_redirect will only rewrite redirect headers, not the HTML content needed for this to work. There is no easy way to rewrite the HTML content in Nginx.

There is the HttpSubModule, which you can manually add text substitutions, but is lengthly to set up each substitution:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule

It is easliest if possible to just update the content at http://local_ip:8079/ to have the redirected path in instead.